# Why does the fringe contrast disappear for a divergent beam (FTIR using a Michelson Interferometer)?

Tags: spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

I am reading "Fourier Transform Spectroscopy" by Griffiths and Haseth.

In section 2.6 Effect of Beam Divergence, the authors state that: When the extreme ray is out of phase with the central ray for the first time "the fringe contrast at the detector disappears completely". Note that here FTIR is carried out using a Michelson Interferometer.

(1) Does the fringe contrast disappear because of the destructive interference between the central and extreme ray?

(2) At an earlier point in the section the authors mention that due to beam divergence Haidinger fringes (see picture) are formed at the detector. The authors mention that the distance between successive maxima decreases with an increasing optical difference (as the mirror is moved in FTIR). Now keeping in mind that this pattern becomes tighter with optical path difference, can the fringe contrast be lost simply because the detector sees the average intensity of this pattern, and the interference pattern is smeared out as the Haidinger fringes become tighter?

So overall, is the fringe contrast lost due to destructive interference, or is it because the Haidinger fringes become tighter? Or is it both?

[image: Figure 2.13 from Griffiths and Haseth]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The detector is a single-pixel sensor. The whole pattern incident on this sensor gets averaged to give a single value of intensity.

Consider what happens when the extreme ray is out of phase with the central ray for the first time. In the center you have the wide fringe with $0°$ relative phase. On the periphery you have a thinner (radially) but longer (angularly) fringe with $180°$ relative phase. As you move the mirror, the constructive and destructive interference swap places, while the average irradiance of the sensor remains virtually the same. Thus, you can't distinguish between these states.

The fringe contrast that you lose is not the contrast in the detection plane: it's the contrast along the mirror path—the path where you actually sample the intensities to get the interferogram.

To limit deviation of the extreme ray from the central ray, Jacquinot stop is used. This leaves only the central fringe on the detector, so contrast is restored.

Comment: Could you elaborate "*As you move the mirror, the constructive and destructive interference swap places, while the average irradiance of the sensor remains virtually the same. Thus, you can't distinguish between these states."*? If we assume this is true, then a interferogram cannot be generated as a function of mirror distance.

Comment: @M.Farooq your conclusion is correct. This is why Jacquinot stop is used: to let only the central fringe reach the detector. Then the interferogram becomes useful.

Comment: @Ruslan that makes sense. However can you clarify "The fringe contrast that you lose is not the contrast in the detection plane: it's the contrast along the mirror path"? Is this due to the destructive interference between the extreme and central rays? Finally, the Jacquinot stop is used to (I) let only the central fringe reach the detector and (II) to reduce the beam width i.e make it more convergent. Is the former statement correct?

Comment: @VinalV interference is not the direct reason for loss of contrast. It's just the simple averaging of the pattern that is. Extreme and central rays don't interfere at all, they are present in the beam and propagate in different directions. What interferes is the two beams after the splitter: one with fixed path length, and another with changeable path.

Comment: As for Jacquinot stop, both (I) and (II) statements are correct, and the latter is the means of achieving the former.

Comment: @Ruslan ah sorry I may not have been clear. In the book, the authors proceed to derive the equation for the maximum solid angle of the beam that can be tolerated on pp.44. In doing so they state that: "As l increases, the extreme ray will be out of phase with the central ray for the first time when" where "l" is the optical path difference. Right after the state "At this point, the fringe contrast at the detector disappears completely, and any further increase in l will add no further information to the interferogram" which is why I asked if the extreme and central ray destructively interfere.

Comment: The condition when fringe contrast disappears according to the authors is when x = 1/2 lambda, where x = optical path difference between the central and extreme rays and Lamba is the wavelength of light used

Comment: @Ruslan, Just by observing the central spot's intensity, aren't we losing information in the intereferogram?

Comment: @M.Farooq no: in the ideal case, when the beam is a flat wave, we only have the central fringe.

Comment: @Ruslan, By the central fringe, you mean the central spot of the circular fringe pattern, if I understand correctly. I have such pictures in mind http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~lecturedemonstrations/Composer/Pages/84.30.html

Comment: @M.Farooq yes, I mean the central part of the two red images at the bottom. The top-right white image was taken with non-coplanar mirrors in the interferometer. I don't think it's a normal setup for a FTIR spectroscope.

Comment: @Ruslan, Right, I have seen a real FTIR interferometer, but rarely any book talks about the image at the detector.